# Pass null to integer in SQL Server from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datatable

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt=//Calling SP which will return a datatable
 dt.Rows[i]["requestid"] = System.DBNull.Value;  // Problem here
```

I also tried

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null
```

but without success. I get an error:

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Please help me out of this.

Comment: That's not really SQL Server, from the looks of it it's an ADO.NET datatable. Why do u want to assign Null to that field?

Comment: Actually Am exporting that column to Excel sheet,That time requestId is duplicated.whereever requestId is duplicated i want to pass null so that Excel cell will be empty instead of duplicate values

Comment: Try this, can you make `requestid` a nullable int like `int?` , and just pass normal `null` to your datatable, instead of the special `DBNull.value` type? 

EDIT: By design, an `int` cannot be null. So if you want to field to be null when you pass to excel, you would need to make that a nullable int, or display it as a `string` and pass `null` that way

Comment: Can u also show how "dt" is being created? Because basically you should be able to store DbNull in an Integer column: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ekTAV

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I have updated my question plz take a look.In DB requestID is integer.DBnull.value is working fine.But now it is throwing an error.dont know where am wrong.

Comment: You could possibly remove and re-add the datarow in question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually implemented my own simulation for this and have C# code which calls a function that runs a SP and returns a DataTable with a column of integers. I'm able to set a cell to `DBNull.Value` without any problems.

This makes me wonder if you're really dealing with the DataTable column types you think you are. I wish I could reproduce this so I could experiment further. If I were you, the next thing I would try is using the debugger to look at DataTable `dt` and see what the types of the columns are.